# Convert .cs variables into .xml file

Tags: c#, xml, variables

I've got this program in C#. I want to convert it into an XML file, and I want to differ between //Input and //Output. For example, it should start writing when read //Input and start writing something else when read //Output. I know I can just write everything by hand to convert it into an XML file, but I need it to be done automatically, so that when I add some variables later I don't have to write these into the XML file by hand.

```cs
class Program
{
    //Input
    public static bool Power = true;     
    public static bool Airflow = true;       
    //Output
    public static bool Cylinder1_Working;

    public static bool Cylinder2_Working;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if ((Power == true) && (Airflow == true))
        {
            Cylinder1_Working = true;
            Cylinder2_Working = true;
        }         
    }
}
```

I need this above converted into this below:

```xml
<LogicDefinition xsi:type="CSharpLogicDefinition"  LogicName="Program">
  <InputVariables>
    <Variable>
      <Name>Power</Name>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <Mode>Input</Mode>
    </Variable>
    <Variable>
      <Name>Airflow</Name>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <Mode>Input</Mode>
    </Variable>
  </InputVariables>  

  <OutputVariables>
    <Variable>
      <Name>Cylinder1_Working</Name>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <Mode>Output</Mode>
    </Variable> 
    <Variable>
      <Name>Cylinder2_Working</Name>
      <Type>Bool</Type>
      <Mode>Output</Mode>
    </Variable>
  </OutputVariables>

  <Version Major="1" Minor="1" Patch="0"  />

  <UserText>
     if ((Power == true) &amp;&amp; (Airflow == true)) {
       Cylinder1_Working = true;
       Cylinder2_Working = true;
     }
  </UserText>
</LogicDefinition>
```

I've looked at `[Serialize]` where I can convert it to XML, but I don't know how to everything by itself. I just need a way how to start with my problem, because Google can't help me with this.

Comment: You can not convert code to XML. `if ((Power == true) && (Airflow == true))
        {
            Cylinder1_Working = true;
            Cylinder2_Working = true;
        } ` You required to write this code as a string into another variable in class and then serialize whole class.

Comment: Ok, but how do I write my variables to XML and differ between Input - Output? The Problem is, that I have to write these Booleans to XML, whether there are 2 or 200 variables.